# Simple way to run a J2EE servlet without installing a full Container

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

If I'm experimenting with J2EE servlet, is there a way to run a `war` without the expense and configuration of fully installing a container like Tomcat? Is there a simple way I can just, for development, download a Java JAR or the like, and do something like `$ java runservlet my.war`?

What is the best practice to run a `war` servlet when just experimenting without the pain of configuring Tomcat?

Comment: Using Tomcat. Which is a web profile container. Don't use a full enterprise profile container (which is more expensive to configure and fully install). If you think Tomcat is too "difficult", try [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you point me at a simple way to use it in my intended use case? The docs I see are all for enterprise deployment and installation.  I'm looking for a simple command line to run, Ctrl-C to stop or the like.

Comment: That is the simple way. Sorry, but there is no "please do what I meant" mode.

Comment: Probably, spring-boot w embedded tomcat?

Comment: The hassle here is a major reason why Spring Boot and Dropwizard have mostly replaced wars.

Comment: @ There is no "best practice", but I second Elliott Frisch's suggestion of Jetty. It's trivial to create a Maven/Jetty web app using any of the leading IDEs, or the command line and a text editor. You can then run Jetty from the command line using `mvn jetty:run` and stop it using Ctrl-C. See [Developing a Standard WebApp with Jetty and Maven](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_and_Maven_HelloWorld#Developing_a_Standard_WebApp_with_Jetty_and_Maven). It details the creation of a simple web that you should have up and running in less than 5 minutes.